# What is the meaning of the addition at the end of this array declaration?

Tags: arrays, matlab, syntax

I'm tasked with implementing an algorithm which was supplied as Matlab (which none of us have any experience with) into our c++ application.

There is an array declared as such:

```
encrypted = [18 10  20  13  6   25  21  13  17;
    2   26  4   29  22  9   5   29  1;
    19  11  21  12  7   24  20  12  16;
    % ... many rows like this ...
    13  21  11  18  25  6   10  18  14]+1;
```

What is the semantic meaning of the `+1` at the end of the array declaration?

Comment: why don't you try it?

Comment: do you really want us to tell you that it computes +1 to each entry?

Comment: I can try it in 3 business days when a sales representative issues me a trial copy of Matlab, unless there is some alternative free interpreter you can recommend?

Comment: Yes honestly that's fine.  I wasn't able to find that documented anywhere, and I'd rather not make guesses about the behaviour of a language. Is that actually what it does, or am I being antagonised and downvoted for not having any experience with Matlab?

Comment: @patchadthat try [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)

Comment: @patchandthat Octave is a good free alternative that is mostly compatible with MATLAB.

Comment: @damienfrancois snap!

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adding 1 to each entry:

```
>> [1 2 3; 4 5 6]

ans =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6

>> [1 2 3; 4 5 6] + 1

ans =

     2     3     4
     5     6     7
```

If you have MATLAB around, you could have figured that out by just trying. If you do not, I hope you have a very clear picture of what the code is doing and write a good test suite, since you won't be able to compare your new code's output to the MATLAB one.

Comment: I don't have a copy of Matlab, although we do have test cases of outputs for the algorithm to verify the overall behavior.  The algorithm generates and encrypts a checksum in a specific manner. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `+1` means that all elements of the written matrix will be increased by one.

**Example**

```
out = [1 2;
       3 4] + 1;

disp(out)
2 3
4 5
```